# Kubuntu 17.04 throttles CPU clock speed, while ElementaryOS doesn't

Tags: kubuntu, cpu, temperature

I have an HP Spectre, on which I had previously installed ElementaryOS. I then recently installed Kubuntu 17.04 and everything works very well, except for one thing.

On ElementaryOS the computer would only start throttling at around 75 degrees Celsius and the fans would, of course, start blowing.
Now on Kubuntu 17.04 it starts throttling at around 50 degrees Celsius and thus, is far from as fast as ElementaryOS at compiling and solving algorithms.

On ElementaryOS the clock speed would be around the rated max speed @ 2800MHz and around 75 degrees Celsius when solving computational problems

On Kubuntu the clock speed is around 1600Mhz and around 50 degrees Celsius when solving computational problems.

My question is, is there any way to change this thermal throttling limit. I have tried turning of the `intel_psate` in the grub config, but it doesn't seem to help.

I know it can go way faster, as I've experienced that on ElementaryOS and also the fans are only spinning at a very low speed (but they are working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Ubuntu / Linux was spawning some processes called `kidle_inject`, which is a process that idles the processor and thus makes it cool down again. These processes are spawned by the kernel module `intel_powerclamp`. It seems as if the `intel_powerclamp` module has been misconfigured somehow and thus spawns these processes at a reasonably low temperature (50 degrees Celsius).

I, therefore, removed the module using `rmmod`:

```
rmmod intel_powerclamp
```

And to make the changes permanent, I also created a file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-intel_powerclamp.conf`

with the content:

```
blacklist intel_powerclamp
```

With these changes, the computer now works again at full speed and performs the same as in ElementaryOS.

Comment: btw, if this didn't solve your problem, simply insert the module again using `insmod intel_powerclamp` and remove the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-intel_powerclamp.conf`

Answer (score 0):

I would use cpufrequtils to check how ubuntu is configured

```
sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils
```

then check what is set now on ubuntu

```
sudo cpufreq-info -p
```

You can check the different policy

```
sudo cpufreq-info -g
```

will return something like

```
conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance
```

now set to on demand or performance

```
sudo cpufreq-set -r -g performance
```

The -r flag is used to set the change for all ("all hardware related") cores

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, it didn't work. I have also tried `sudo echo performance | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
` and I can see that it sets it to performance. However, it still throttles down when reaching 50 degrees Celsius. Is there a config somewhere where a limit like this could be changed?

Comment: disable ondemand daemon, otherwise after you reboot the settings will be overwritten.

`sudo update-rc.d ondemand disable`   and make sure you do `sudo /etc/init.d/cpufrequtils restart`  you can also try to set the speed of cpu to max, query to see at which speed it throttles to keep 50°C.